# Is there a standard place to put all my websites in linux/nginx?

Tags: linux, nginx

I'm used to put them in /var/www or /home/www with a symlynk to /var/www when using apache. Not sure why, but I read that it was a security matter.

Is that the place for nginx websites too?

Answer (score 2):

The most appropriate place for web content under *any* server is [under `/srv`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM).

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a standard, then the standard would be defined by the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://proton.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html).  This standard says that they should be located beneath `/srv`.  If the data is owned by one particular user, then locating the files under that user's home directory is also appropriate.  `/var/www` is the most common location for this.  However, this directory is not defined by the standard.

Answer (score 1):

I'm mostly using `/home/$site-owning-user/foo.bar.com/(htdocs|logs)`, as the sites my servers host are user-controlled; or `/home/$site-owning-group/...` if multiple users are controlling a site. This keeps all of a user's files together for easier backup and monitoring and such.

For non-user-controlled sites (eg webapps installed by the sysadmin from packages), `/srv` probably makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

Since Nginx has the `root` directive to point to where files are, choosing the place to put them really is mostly a matter of taste and setup needs.

However it is common Practice to either put them in `/www`, `/var/www`, or `/srv/www` with the later a symlink to `/var/www` (depending on the distro)